# joomla 2.5 virtuemart php 5.2

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

i have a problem with joomla virtuemart.

> Fatal error: Class 'shopFunctionsF' not found in
>   /home/eneskura/public_html/components/com_virtuemart/views/virtuemart/view.html.php
>   on line 40

line 40

> [line38] $vendor = $vendorModel->getVendor();      if (VmConfig::get
>
> [line39] ('enable_content_plugin', 0)) {
>
> [line40]           shopFunctionsF::triggerContentPlugin($vendor,
>
> [line41] 'vendor','vendor_store_desc');
>
> [line42]           shopFunctionsF::triggerContentPlugin($vendor,'vendor','vendor_terms_of_service');       }

non-added lines

> $vendor = $vendorModel->getVendor();      if (VmConfig::get
>   ('enable_content_plugin', 0)) {
>             shopFunctionsF::triggerContentPlugin($vendor,
>   'vendor','vendor_store_desc');
>             shopFunctionsF::triggerContentPlugin($vendor,
>   'vendor','vendor_terms_of_service');      }

i cant find a way to run it.

php 5.2

Comment: if you install the last version, you should switch to php 5.3+ as it's recommended by virtuemart developper team

Comment: Sorry but my server will not do that.

Answer (score 0):

When I was getting the "Class 'shopFunctionsF' not found" error message, I found the problem was that Virtuemart had no menu items associated with it.

Setting up a virtuemart menu item fixed it for me.

This is not a guaranteed fix for your issue, but this is the only thread that mentions that specific error message, so I suspect it may be the same problem.